# DSM docker parse-server can't access cloud code or config file

Tags: docker, parse-platform, parse-server, docker-container, synology

I've used [yongjhih/parse-server](https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/yongjhih/parse-server) as my container image for a while, but this image wasn't updated over 4 years so I moved to the official [parseplatform/parse-server](https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/parseplatform/parse-server) image, and connected it to the [parse-dashboard](https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/parseplatform/parse-dashboard) official image.
Both working fine, and I've successfully saved objects to the DB using the dashboard console.

Problems:

1. My parse-server ignoring `config.json` file on mounted folder, so for now I use only environment variables.
2. When trying to access cloud code via REST console I get `404 (Not Found)` on inspector with response `Cannot GET /parse/endpointName`. but I don't get any error or warnings on logs.
3. I've also disabled GraphQL and playground for now because it's making the whole container crash with an error `GraphQLError [Object]: Syntax Error: Unexpected Name "const"`, which probably means I'm missing some imports, but it also means the server can actually access my mounted folders.
4. Dashboard can't access parse-server via local host, I solved it by using ip address for `serverURL` on the dashboard `config.json`

I'm using the docker (GUI) app on my Synology NAS with DSM 7.

My volumes:
[image]

Environment variables:
[image]

My dashboard config.json:

```
{
  "apps": [{
    "serverURL": "http://192.168.1.5:1337/parse",
    "appId": "appId",
    "masterKey": "masterKey",
    "appName": "appName"
  }],
  "users": 
  [
    {
        "user":"user",
        "pass":"pass"
    }
  ]
}
```

--------------------------Edit--------------------------
So moving from such an old server to the new image meant a lot of changes

1. Cloud code is accessible, just needed to fix syntax a bit
2. GraphQL is now [Relay](https://relay.dev/docs/) so I'll have to fix my `schema.js` too.

Still can't find a way to use config file instead of environment variables

Comment: Can you share how you are testing the cloud code via REST console? The url should be something like /parse/functions/functionName and it should be a POST request.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo thanks I didn't realize I need to use POST instead of GET. when I POST `/functions/hello` I get error response 141 `Cannot read property 'success' of undefined`, my cloud function looks like `Parse.Cloud.define('hello', function(req, res) {
  res.success('Hi');
});`

Comment: OK, I got it, the syntax that worked on the old server was wrong, or old, changed it to `return "Hi"` now it works. so I can access cloud code, now I need to figure out whats wrong with GraphQL